# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.1 (Elastic Beanstalk port help)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

First my experience... zero to 1 on a scale of 100...

I have an `index.js` file, and an `index.ejs` file which works well on a localhost. From tutorial https://itnext.io/build-a-group-chat-app-in-30-lines-using-node-js-15bfe7a2417b

I believe the problem is setting up the listen and host extracts of those codes:

From the index.js

```
const server = http.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
```

From the index.ejs

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

When I deploy and run on AWS Beanstalk I get this

502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.14.1

I found that AWS Beanstalk uses port 8081, so I changed all the 8080s to 8081, then redeploy with the same error.

That the chat program runs on my beanstalk, like my localhost.